# Laravel creating entry with multiple selection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 table, `RecipesTable` & `IngredientsTable`.

IngredientsTable:

```
class IngredientsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('ingredient_name');
        });
    }
}
```

RecipesTable :

```
class RecipesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('recipe_name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('ingredient_id');
            $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredient');
        });
    }
}
```

Let say in my `RecipesTable` table entry I have a recipe call `Fried Chicken` and my `IngredientsTable` I have 4 entry : `1, Chicken`, `2, Dory`, `3, Salt`, `4, Breadcrumb`. 
How can I create an entry that associate multiple entry of `IngredientsTable` into `RecipesTable` in my Controller? for example my entry should look like this in JSON :
Recipe :

```
{
    id: 1
    name : 'Friend Chicken'
    ingredient_id ; ['1', '3', '4']
}
```

Right now in my Controller I have something like this :

```
public function createRecipe(Request $request )
    {
            $data = ([
                'recipe_name' => 'Fried Chicken',
                'ingredient_id' => ['1', '3', '4'],
                ])

            Recipe::create($data);
            return redirect()->route('recipe.index')->withStatus(__('Recipe has been added.'));
        }        
    }
```

and its not working.

Comment: You need to use many-to-many relation here.
It means you need another table which will associate your recipes with ingradients. Laravel is supporting that type of relations. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Also note, that you need table like this `recipe_ingradient_relation`

Where you will have `id`, `recipe_id`, `ingradient_id`

Comment: Also see https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: thanks, I'm looking at it right now

Comment: I have posted an answer, try it and let me know it is working or no :)

Comment: @RobMkrtchyan Hi, thanks your update check it on it now, sorry I was away for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new migration:

```
class RecipeIngredientRelTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recipe_ingredient_rel', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigIncrements('recipe_id')->index();
            $table->bigIncrements('ingredient_id')->index();

            $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipes');
            $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredient');
        });
    }
}
```

Add model

```
class RecipeIngredientRel extends BaseModel
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'recipe_id',
        'ingredient_id'
    ];

    public function recipe(){
        return parent::belongsTo(Recipe::class);
    }

    public function ingredient(){
        return parent::belongsTo(Ingredient::class);
    }
}
```

In your recipes model add

```
public function ingredients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'recipe_ingredient_rel', 'recipe_id');
}
```

In your ingredients model add

```
public function recipes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'recipe_ingredient_rel', 'ingredient_id');
}
```

Then, in controller Just write

```
Recipe::create([
    'recipe_name' => $data['recipe_name']
])->attach($data['ingredient_id']);
```

It will create entity in recipes table with name
And 3 entities in recipe_ingredient_rel table with

```
recipe_id => {created_id} | ingredient_id => 1
recipe_id => {created_id} | ingredient_id => 2
recipe_id => {created_id} | ingredient_id => 2
```

Then to retrieve recipe with ingredients, just use

```
$recipe = Recipe::with('ingredients')->find({created_id});
```

It will give you Collection, just use toArray() to see the actual result.

**UPDATE**

```
    Recipe::create([
        'recipe_name' => $data['recipe_name']
    ])->ingredients()->attach($data['ingredient_id']);
```

This one should work

Comment: Thanks @Rob I'm trying this right now, will let you know when it worked

Comment: Hi @Rob I Tried this and it says `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ` when creating the entry

Comment: Are you sure you have all ingradients in db? 
For this example you should have idngedients with id: 1, id: 3 and id:4

Comment: Yes I have all the ingredient in db

Comment: for this part `->attach($data['ingredient_id']);` does the data should look like this `->attach($data[['1', '2', '4']]);` or I need to do for each to loop the ingredient ID?

Comment: Remove ingredient_id from recipes table. That error is thrown on recipes table, not on rel)))

Comment: hi this seem to fix the problem, thank you so much fo your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change your migrations. Since a recipe has many ingredients. **One to Many relationship** approach

**Recipe Migration:**

```
Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('recipe_name'); 
});
```

**Ingredients Migration:**

```
Schema::create('ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('recipe_id');
    $table->string('ingredient_name');

    $table->foreign('recipe_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('recipes')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

---

Create a *model* for each **Recipe** and **Ingredient** table and add relationship:

**Recipe model**

```
class Recipe
{
    protected $table = 'recipes';
    //fill the fillables here

    public function ingredient(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ingredient');
    }
}
```

**Ingredient model**

```
class Ingredient
{
    protected $table = 'ingredients';
    //fill the fillables here

    public function ingredient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
    }
}
```

---

Now in your question how to add:

Create first the **recipe**:

```
$value = 'fried chicken';

$recipe = Recipe::create([
    'recipe_name' => $value
]);
```

And then insert the **ingredients** of the recipe:

```
$ingredients = ['flour', 'salt', 'oil', 'chicken'];
foreach($ingredients AS $value){
    $recipe->ingredient()->create([
        'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
        'ingredient_name' => $value
    ]);
}
```

---

Display the ingredients of fried chicken:

```
//search the recipe
$recipe = Recipe:where('recipe_name', 'fried chicken')->first();

//display ingredients
return $recipe->ingredient;
```

---

> NOTE: This is just to answer the question, scroll down more to see the other approach.

Comment: How you will create another recipe with same ingradients?

Comment: @RobMkrtchyan this is One to Many relationship brother.

Comment: Yeah, but seems he need many-to-many :) Ingradients can be duplicated for different recipes, so with one-to-many you will have many duplicated rows in ingradients table

Comment: @RobMkrtchyan he can use other approach as what I say :) But I will use this approach if I was he. I will try to make a Many to Many for him, I will edit this

Comment: Hi @suspended thanks for the answer and yes as Rob said I want to re use the ingredient for the next recipe i created.

Comment: @M.Izzat did you get the answer of your question brother? Hmm. I can give you the Many to Many relationship if you want.

Comment: @suspended Im trying the answer provided by Rob on top I will update you once I'm done with it, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @M.Izzat okay ywc

Answer (score 1):

Just do these thing in your controller:

```
public function createRecipe(Request $request )
    {

            $data = ([
                'recipe_name' => 'request('name')',
                'ingredient_id' => 'serialize(request('ingredient_id '))',
                ])

            Recipe::create($data);
            return redirect()->route('recipe.index')->withStatus(__('Recipe has been added.'));
        }        
    }
```

While retrieve use `unserialize` to get data `['1', '3', '4']` in these format.I hope it may help you.Try this.